# Parse kml file to show multiple Placemark in google earth

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, google-earth

I would like to show multiple Placemarks by parsing a kml file. Please help, Im stuck for long days.

As I see google earth desktop client works well for following kml code snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

<Document>    
  <Placemark>
    <name>Placemark2 from KML file</name>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.448425,36.802907,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Placemark2 from KML file</name>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.448425,37.802907,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</Document> 
</kml>
```

Based on the above code snippet I tried by following to show multiple placemark at first look. But NO LUCK. I prefer to parse kml string instead of fetching a .kml file, kml file need to be publicly available and reachable by Google. Moreover by parsing kml string we can test it from localhost.

```
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAA5El50zA4PeDTEMlv-sXFfRSsTL4WIgxhMZ0ZK_kHjwHeQuOD4xTdBhxbkZWuzyYTVeclkwYHpb17ZQ"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ge;
    var placemark;
    var object;

    google.load("earth", "1");

    function init() {
        google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
    }

    function initCB(instance) {
        ge = instance;
        ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
        var kmlString = ''
                        + '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
                        + '<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">'
                        + '<Document>'                           
                        + '<Placemark>'
                            + '<name>Placemark1</name>'
                            + '<description>Some Descriptive text.</description>'
                            + '<Point>'
                            + '<coordinates>-122.448425,36.802907,0</coordinates>'
                            + '</Point>'
                        + '</Placemark>'
                        + '<Placemark>'
                            + '<name>Placemark2</name>'
                            + '<Point>'
                            + '<coordinates>-122.448425,37.802907,0</coordinates>'
                            + '</Point>'
                        + '</Placemark>'
                        + '</Document>'
                        + '</kml>';

        var kmlObject = ge.parseKml(kmlString);
        ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
        ge.getView().setAbstractView(kmlObject.getAbstractView());
    }

    function failureCB(errorCode) {
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
</script>
<div id="map3d" style="border: 1px solid silver; height: 400px; width: 600px;">
</div>
```

If I add following camera tag in document then one Placemark is shown. All placemark can be shown by zoom out.

```
+ '<Camera>'
      + '<longitude>-122.448425</longitude>'
      + '<latitude>36.802907</latitude>'
      + '<altitude>100</altitude >'                             
      + '<tilt>10</tilt>'
      + '<heading>2.7</heading>'
  + '</Camera>'
```

Have any idea, How can I show mulitple placemark at first look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display kml on google earth we have three methods:

1.From kml networklink
2.fetching data from url
3.fetching data from kml string

By specifying `altitude as 100` in your kml,onload google earth display `-122.448425,36.802907` placemark with altitude as 100.So,increase your altitude then you can view all your placemarks.I tried in my machine with `altitude as 1000000` .Two placemarks are visible onload of google earth.

**NOTE:** If you have so many placemarks then increase your altitude or else go for dynamic kml generation using server-side code with high altitude.Hope this helps you :-)